# Why is my WSUS Server itself appearing in "Unassigned Computers" within the WSUS Console, even though it is in an Active Directory OU?

Tags: active-directory, group-policy, wsus

I have my WSUS linked to Active Directory via group policy.
My WSUS server is contained within my "Servers" OU on Active Directory. I have multiple servers in this OU.

However once I look at the WSUS console, the WSUS Server itself has been placed in the "Unassigned Computers" folder. All of the rest of the the servers in the OU have been placed in my "Servers" folder within the WSUS console.

Does anyone know why this is happening? I have run gpupdate /force on the WSUS server, and have double checked that it is definitely on the correct OU on Active Directory.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem can be caused by many reasons. Here's what to check:

1. Ensure the GPO configuration applies to that server (gpresult /v).
2. You can also check if WU settings are applied correctly on *that
   particular server* with regedit, under:
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate.
   There you can ensure that targeting is correct (TargetGroup &
   TargetGroupEnabled items)
3. Check WU logs at c:\windows\windowsupdate.log

Comment: Thanks mate. I really appreciate the reply after the question got no answers for days. This really helps me!